# How to switch to different branch but maintain folders and commit history

Tags: git

I am not very articulate but I will try my best to explain the scenario.

There's a remote GitHub repo with one branch, master. In one meeting, it was decided to continue development on a different branch, named dev. I did not see that message and committed to master. A few other commits have now been made on the master branch by other contributors. I want to switch to the dev branch and start coding there. I do not want my previous commit to still be present in master.

So what should I do in this case, where I want to "shift" my past commits into dev from the master, removing all traces from the latter, but subsequent commits have been made to master.

This is my first time asking on StackOverflow and I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: May you share the commit tree, and how you would like it to look?

Answer (score -1):

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard master
```

**Note:** Hard rests and force pushes can destroy work so it's very important that you back up uncommitted changes and tell everyone using the repository if you need to force push

Answer (score -1):

You would need to do a series of `git revert` and `git cherry-pick`. Here are the steps:

1. Identify the hash of the accidental commits that you made on the master branch. Use `git log` if you are using command line or get them from your git client.
2. Checkout the master branch and run the following `git revert` command. You need to list the commit hashes from the latest until the earliest order. The `git revert` command will create as many new commits as the number of commits you list):

```
git revert commit_hash3 commit_hash2 commit_hash1
```

3. Then checkout the dev branch and run the `git cherry-pick` command using the same list of commit hashes **but in reverse order**, which is from the earliest to the latest. The `git cherry-pick` command will create one new commit for each source commit:

```
git cherry-pick commit_hash1 commit_hash2 commit_hash3
```

4. If at any point during the cherry-pick there is a merge conflict, you would need to manually resolve it before doing `git add -A` and `git commit`. Then, run `git cherry-pick --continue` until all the commits have been cherry-picked.

The result of all the steps will look something like below:

[image: Demo]